# Generate tds outside each input field in dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

This is my first question on stackoverflow and i'm totally newbie to dartlang.

I have 8 input fields which i created using this:

```dart
InputElement in1 = new InputElement();
 in1.placeholder = "№";
InputElement in2 = new InputElement();
 in2.placeholder = "Name";
... 
InputElement in8 = new InputElement();
 in8.placeholder = "Date";
```

And i couldn't figure out how to automatically generate row with tds containing those input fields. If i create it manually my code would look like this:

```dart
InputElement in1 = new InputElement();
 in1.placeholder = "№";
TableCellElement cell1 = new Element.td();
 cell1.nodes.add(in1);
InputElement in2 = new InputElement();
 in2.placeholder = "Name";
TableCellElement cell2 = new Element.td();
 cell2.nodes.add(in2);
InputElement in3 = new InputElement();
 in3.placeholder = "LastName";
TableCellElement cell3 = new Element.td();
 cell3.nodes.add(in3);
InputElement in4 = new InputElement();
 in4.placeholder = "Register No";
TableCellElement cell4 = new Element.td();
 cell4.nodes.add(in4);
InputElement in5 = new InputElement();
 in5.placeholder = "University";
TableCellElement cell5 = new Element.td();
 cell5.nodes.add(in5);
InputElement in6 = new InputElement();
 in6.placeholder = "Occupation";
TableCellElement cell6 = new Element.td();
 cell6.nodes.add(in6);
InputElement in7 = new InputElement();
 in7.placeholder = "Grade";
TableCellElement cell7 = new Element.td();
 cell7.nodes.add(in7);
InputElement in8 = new InputElement();
 in8.placeholder = "Date";
TableCellElement cell8 = new Element.td();
 cell8.nodes.add(in8);

  TableRowElement tr1 = new Element.tr();
  tr1.classes.add("table-header-student");

  tr1.nodes.add(cell1);
  tr1.nodes.add(cell2);
  tr1.nodes.add(cell3);
  tr1.nodes.add(cell4);
  tr1.nodes.add(cell5);
  tr1.nodes.add(cell6);
  tr1.nodes.add(cell7);
  tr1.nodes.add(cell8);
```

I don't wanna create it manually cuz i need to do it on other tables with different columns. And the reason i'm creating these input field is to create filtering. 
Pls don't suggest innerHtml, appendHtml cuz i have to create it with purely dart code.
I think it's possible to do by making list and using loop but i don't know how. Pls help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but I assume this is what you want.

```dart
List<String> placeholders = ['№', 'Name', 'LastName', 'Register No', 'University', 'Occupation', 'Grade', 'Date'];

TableRowElement tr = new Element.tr()
    ..classes.add("table-header-student");

placeholders.forEach((ph) {
  tr.append(new TableCellElement()..append(new InputElement()..placeholder = ph));
});

querySelector('table').append(tr);
```

example with more attributes (not tested)

```dart
List<String> fields = [
  {'placeholder': '№', 'id': 'id1', 'name': 'name1'}, 
  {'placeholder': 'Name', 'id': 'id2', 'name': 'name2'}, 
  {'placeholder': 'LastName', 'id': 'id3', 'name': 'name3'}, 
  {'placeholder': 'Register No', 'id': 'id4', 'name': 'name4'}, 
  {'placeholder': 'University', 'id': 'id5', 'name': 'name5'}, 
  {'placeholder': 'Occupation', 'id': 'id6', 'name': 'name6'}, 
  {'placeholder': 'Grade', 'id': 'id7', 'name': 'name7'}, 
  {'placeholder': 'Date', 'id': 'id8', 'name': 'name8'}];

TableRowElement tr = new Element.tr()
    ..classes.add("table-header-student");

fields.forEach((f) {
  tr.append(new TableCellElement()..append(
      new InputElement()
          ..placeholder = f['placeholder']
          ..id = f['id']
          ..name = f['name']
  ));
});

querySelector('table').append(tr);
```

If your element creation logic becomes more complicated I would create a function/method for this

```dart
main() {
  List<String> fields = [
    {'placeholder': '№', 'id': 'id1', 'name': 'name1'}, 
    {'placeholder': 'Name', 'id': 'id2', 'name': 'name2'}, 
    {'placeholder': 'LastName', 'id': 'id3', 'name': 'name3'}, 
    {'placeholder': 'Register No', 'id': 'id4', 'name': 'name4'}, 
    {'placeholder': 'University', 'id': 'id5', 'name': 'name5'}, 
    {'placeholder': 'Occupation', 'id': 'id6', 'name': 'name6'}, 
    {'placeholder': 'Grade', 'id': 'id7', 'name': 'name7'}, 
    {'placeholder': 'Date', 'id': 'id8', 'name': 'name8'}];

  TableRowElement tr = new Element.tr()
      ..classes.add("table-header-student");

  fields.forEach((f) {
    tr.append(new TableCellElement()..append(createInputElement(f));
  });

  querySelector('table').append(tr);
}

InputElement createInputElement(Map metadata) {
  var ie = new InputElement();
  if(metadata['placeholder'] != null) ie.placeholder = metadata['placeholder'];
  if(metadata['id'] != null) ie.id = metadata['id'];
  if(metadata['name'] != null) ie.name = metadata['name'];
  // ... more element customization
  return ie;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Almost exactly what i wanted. But what if i want to add other attributes aside from ph like id, name etc to my input fields???

Comment: Only thing that could become complicated for me is that if some field  must be changed into other kind of field. For example Grade column has only [1,2,3,4] values. So it would be easier to filter table with dropdown list instead of input. If it's the last or the first field i could create it manually and append others with your code. But if i have to change the random fields from my table i guess i have no other choice but to create it manually one by one :(. Do you have any idea to solve this easily?

Comment: This isn't difficult either. Use my last version with the `createInputElement()` method. You can either add a 'type' field to the metadata or some other criteria which you can use to decide which field type to use.
Then add an `if` or `switch` in `createInputElement`. `if(metadata['type'] == 'dropdown' return new SelectElement()..id = metadata['id'] ... } else { return new TextInputElement()..id=metadata['id']...}` You have to change the return type of `createInputElement` to `HtmlElement` (or just remove it)

Comment: Okay i'll try that tomorrow. I learned a lot from you today. Thank you :)